# Update with Spatial Subselect extreme slow on SQL Server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, geospatial

i have a simple Update Query that update a single field.

```
Update tracks SET facility_id = (SELECT TOP 1 facility_id FROM facilities ORDER BY location.STDistance(tracks.location) ASC)
```

I have a "tracks" table with millions of entries (tracking data) and a "facilities" table (about 400 entries). Each have a location Field (with a geographical point). What i want to do is to find the nearest Facility for each entry in "tracks".

This performes realy bad on MS SQL Server 2008 r2 ... only 16 Rows / second. Same as Denali.

BTW: Postgres 8.4 Updates about 1000 rows / second in a VirtualMachine!!!

What would you opimize to get better Performance?

Greetz,

Matze

Comment: Do you have a spatial index on `facilites.location`?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have one, as a1ex07 says create a spatial index, but then also use an index hint.